# BitBucket CI/CD pipeline - changing file permissions in a test fails in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a test to make sure the application provides a proper error if it can not access a file. To do so, the test changes the file permission, that it runs the application and checks the error.

Something like:

```
public void permissions() {
  String file = prepareFiles(); // let's say this creates a file /tmp/myfiles/filetocheck

  Path path = Paths.get(file).getParent();
  Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("---------"));

  MyApp.main();

  thenLogContains("no access to " + file + ": java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException")
}
```

It works locally, but when it runs in the BitBucket pipeline, it fails because permissions have not been changed. Has anybody ran into the same problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For beginners like me: the problem was simply that the docker container runs as root, therefore even changing the permissions, the file was still readable from maven.

[This post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-run-Bitbucket-Pipeline-as-non-root-user/qaq-p/681049) indicated how resolve the problem by creating a new user and run maven as such user.